# How can I track firebase New dataLayer schema in Universal Analytics

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-firebase

We have a few questions about the case that we cannot find any solution method. Our customer wants to track their mobile app data on GA4 and Universal Analytics.

Our question is about the Universal Analytics side, on Purchase step we fired this kind of data structure model you can find details in below,

This structure is for creating item bundle which uses in Purchase step:

[image]

This structure below is for sending Purchase parameters under Purchase event (it’s same as Firebase documentation):

[image]

This structure is for sending events to Universal Analytics property. We created GA tag on app GTM container and send `eventCategory`, `eventAction` and `eventLabel` parameter dynamically.

[image]

In the summary in Universal Analytics property we can see the number of events that we send via eecEvent trigger but on the other hand we cannot see any Purchase under Enhanced E Commerce reports. I also share our tag structure details below. Do you have any opinion about these situation please let us to know if you needed any diffrent detail.

[image]
[image]
[image]